# Recognizing the return of a casual user through the Flask user session

Tags: python, session, flask, sqlalchemy

Consider a web site that persists on disk the activitiy of its users, without requiring them to log-in/authenticate.

This would enable the user to return and find all their activity intact, even if the server had been relaunched.

Because the user session

```
from Flask import session
session['foo'] = 'bar'
```

is an ordinary dict, I'm assuming it gets wiped when the server is stopped and relaunched. It is hence not persistent if the user's two visits cross a server relaunch.

To do so using Flask, we'd use a database session

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
db.session.add(..)
db.session.commit()
```

and, since users are not logged-in, we'd distinguish between distinct users through their *user* sessions.

What is a unique ID that can be extracted from the user session to persist in a database session? The idea is that when a user returns, the cookie in their browser would identify them uniquely, which in turn would mean that the identifier we'd hash from the user session would remain intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the terminology I assume you are using Flask -

So, the `db.session` does not refer to the "browsing" session, with date related to a single viewer-  ratehr, it refers to a db connection session that is unique for that web view cycle (and not for the browsing session) - these are different things.

And as such, the code above *do* persist your object on the DB in a permanent, unique way. If you can't see them when restarting the Flask application it must be because you are using a transient database. Just adjust your configurations to use a permanent - in disk - database, instead of either an in-memory sqlite instance, or a database inside a docker  container that is re-created every time.

The "session" you are thinking of, as "browsing" session does not exist out-of the box in Flask-  you either roll yur own, or use one of the plug-ins such as https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/ - this is what is related to PHP's "session".